# Partial Derivative of $f(x,y) =\ln(x^{2} + y^{2}) + \sqrt{x^{2}\cdot y^{3}}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

$$f(x,y) = \ln(x^{2} + y^{2}) + \sqrt{x^{2}\cdot y^{3}}$$
What is the value of $f_{x}\left ( 0,1 \right )$ and $f_{y}\left ( 0,1 \right )$?
I tried but I found the denominator as zero.

Comment: It is not because $f_x(t,1)$ does not converge when $t$ tends to $0$ that $f_x(0,1)$ does not exist. It can just be that $f_x$ is discontinuous at $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x) = \ln(x^2+y^2) + \sqrt{x^2y^3} = \ln(x^2+y^2) + |x|y^3$$

Now, $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$, so $f_x$ doesn't exist along the line $x=0$. $f_y$ doesn't have that problem; evaluating should give $f_y(0,1) = 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the denominator would be zero, e.g.

$f_x(x,y) = 2x / (x^2 + y^2)  + xy^3 (x^2 y^3)^{-1/2}$

$f_x(x,y) = 2x / (x^2 + y^2)  + y^{3/2}$

$f_x(0,1) = 0 / (0 + 1)  + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x,y) = \ln(x^{2} + y^{2}) + \sqrt{x^{2}\cdot y^{3}}$$
Using chain rule of differentiation:

$$
\begin{align}
f_x(x, y) &= \dfrac{2x}{x^2 + y^2} + \dfrac{1}{2} 2xy^3 \left(x^2 \cdot y^3\right)^{\frac{-1}{2}} \\
&= \dfrac{2x}{x^2 + y^2} + \dfrac{xy^3}{\sqrt{x^2 \cdot y^3}} \\
&= \dfrac{2x}{x^2 + y^2} + y^{\frac{3}{2}}
\end{align}
$$
Similarly,

$$
\begin{align}
f_y(x, y) &= \dfrac{2y}{x^2 + y^2} + \dfrac{1}{2} 3x^2y^2 \left(x^2 \cdot y^3\right)^{\frac{-1}{2}} \\
&= \dfrac{2y}{x^2 + y^2} + 3xy^{\frac{1}{2}}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: $\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2}} \ne 1$.